# Connect google-sites webpage to cPanel domain

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-hosting, google-sites

I want to publish my google-sites webpage in a custom domain. This domain is hosted on cPanel. I read a couple of tutorials and references, and below is a summary of what I tried:

1. Create new subdomain on cPanel.
2. Add TXT record of google site verification key for subdomain.
3. Add CNAME record of  "ghs.googlehosted.com." destination for subdomain.
4. Verify property of subdomain in google search console.
5. Connect custom domain in google sites

I have no experience in using cPanel for web hosting. This subdomain site appears to be out of reach one day after configuring DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to contact your hosting provider and ask them how they handle google-sites webpage. I also think it's possible without a subdomain unless you intend to make it so.